# Tshark outputs json during live capture

Tags: json, tshark

i want to run tshark for a live capture of my internet traffic my goal is to save the captures in json files in a folder now i'm using :

```
  tshark -P -i 4 -w outfile.pcap
```

The prolem with this cxommand is that the output file is one gigantic file that i can't use while tshark is running and it's not json .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-T json` option instructs tshark to output JSON:

```
tshark -T json -i 4 > outfile.json
```

Comment: What about writing data in different files (outfile 1,2,....) because the one file is not suitable not usable for a streaming app .

Comment: That's a whole other question. You might find some ideas here: https://superuser.com/questions/291368/log-rotation-of-stdout